# Ruby on Rails assets/images are accessible to users not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, session, assets

When I load an image link into the URL it loads the images even if the person is not logged in.

For example,

this link takes me to login: `website.net`

this link takes me to an image file (without logging in) `website.net/assets/idaho/idaho_ellen_mitchell_sig.png`

I don't want that image file to load if the user isn't logged in.

I'm new to RoR and am really unsure where to start with this problem.

Is this a sessions issue? Security issue?

My gut tells me I'll need to use NGINX to make this work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post more details about this action "When I load an image link into the URL."

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is, that you placed your images in the assets folder, which is public.
You can solve your problem with the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

The documentation is great and you will surely find your way around it.